# Use a different specifier value in place of an empty one

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating a sort of "Override" function for an iOS tweak an I've run into a problem.

I want to be able to use a central value to use when an override value isn't there, set as a different key.

I've seen that you can do this

```
CGFloat value = [dict objectForKey:key] ? [[dict objectForKey:key] floatValue] : 0.0;
```

but that only sets it as a static value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use another value stored in the dictionary instead of the 0.0.

You can do it like:

```
CGFloat value = [dict objectForKey:key] ? [[dict objectForKey:key] floatValue] : [[dict objectForKey:anotherKey] floatValue];
```